# Is it possible to check if a livestream url is playable before loading it into a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My question is not in regards to checking whether the livestream URL is valid, but rather if it's playable.

Currently I load a livestream video url with an .m3u8 extension into a `UIWebView`.

Occasionally, the livestream is not playable, however it is still accessible. I'd like to somehow determine if the url is playable and display a message to the screen stating "livestream down..." instead of a gray `UIWebView` window with a play button that does nothing when tapped.

Is this possible or can anyone suggest an alternative method?

Thanks

Comment: Just an idea... what about start streaming using nsurlconnection and checking if you receive data?

Comment: you can try canOpenUrl first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend streaming those files using a designated player. If you play those files using a WebView you can load them first inside a player just for the state check. Here's a `MPMoviePlayerController` example on how to do it:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:)                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object:player];
if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
{
...
}
```

Checking `loadState` will tell you the state of the stream:

```
enum {
   MPMovieLoadStateUnknown        = 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlayable       = 1 << 0,
   MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK  = 1 << 1,
   MPMovieLoadStateStalled        = 1 << 2,
};
```

Because `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated on iOS 9 i'd advise to search for the above equivalent using `AVPlayerViewController` for recent iOS versions.